# Of three SELECT menus, only one will show ... what am I missing?

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form

I have a form with three (3) Zend_Form_Element_Select()'s, and I include them all in the *addElements* call.
Only the last one in the *addElements* array will show.

Here's my form code:

```
class Form_MapBomForm extends Zend_Form {
    public function init($option = null) {
        parent::init($option);   

        // instantiate a numbered options list for the SELECT's
        $options = array(
            NULL  => ' - please select - ',
            1   =>  '1 (first)',
            2   =>  '2 (second)',
            3   =>  '3 (third)',
            4   =>  '4 (fourth)', 
            5   =>  '5 (fifth)',
            6   =>  '6 (sixth)', 
            7   =>  '7 (seventh)'
        );

        $pn_col = new Zend_Form_Element_Select('pn');
        $pn_col->setLabel('PN Column:')
            ->addMultiOptions($options)
            //->setRequired(TRUE)
            //->addValidator('NotEmpty')
            ;

        $qty_col = new Zend_Form_Element_Select('pn');
        $qty_col->setLabel('Qty Column:')
            ->addMultiOptions($options)
            //->setRequired(TRUE)
            //->addValidator('NotEmpty')
            ; 

        $first_row = new Zend_Form_Element_Select('pn');
        $first_row->setLabel('Start ROW For PN\'s:')
            ->addMultiOptions($options)
            //->setRequired(TRUE)
            //->addValidator('NotEmpty')
            ;

        $submit = new Zend_Form_Element_Submit('submit');
        $submit->setLabel('Save Mapping');

        $this->addElements(array(  $pn_col, $qty_col, $first_row, $submit  ))
            ->setName('bommap')
            ->setMethod('post')
            ;
    }
}
```

I can switch the order of adding the elements, and regardless, only the last of the three SELECT's shows with the submit button.

Please help.
~ Mo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are giving all the select elements the same name 'pn'. Try giving them different names, e.g.:

```
...
$pn_col = new Zend_Form_Element_Select('pn');
...
$qty_col = new Zend_Form_Element_Select('qty');
...
$first_row = new Zend_Form_Element_Select('f');
...
```